# =REGEXTRACT() for file extensions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I have thousands of file names to filter in Google Sheets and I need to extract only their file extensions.

Below are two samples of NAME FORMAT:

```
1) xxx.[file extension]
2) xxx.xxx.[file extension]
```

I need to extract only the file extensions and I tried the below with no success:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B4,"\..*")
```

The function above worked fine for names with FORMAT 1, but not FORMAT 2.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: try this :- `.*\..*$`

https://regex101.com/r/nQ7rG9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
.*\.(.+)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ7rG9/2)**

*A bit of modification*

```
\.([^.]+)$
```

Comment: The leading `.*` isn't really doing anything here.

Comment: @Jordan it will be needed to make the match greedy.

Comment: Wow, it works!, anyone one care to explain? trying to learn RegEx here. :)

Comment: @Pete its a greedy regex because of `.*`..It will match till last `.`..and whatever follows after `.` will be stored in capturing group

Comment: @Pete you can accept the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped

Comment: @rock321987 Hey, I've just accepted by ticking, sorry that I didnt know earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @rock321987, Hi, sorry just another question, how do I capture the dot?

Comment: @Pete just include it in capturing group as `.*(\..+)$`

Answer (score 1):

This one works flawlessly:

```
\.([^.]+)$
# not a dot
# one or more times
# bind it to the end of the string/line
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lQ2xW7/3)</kbd>.
Thanks to @Jordan for pointing out a flaw before (not at least one dot is required).

Comment: Note that if the value doesn't have a dot, this will match the whole value (e.g. it will match `bar` in `foo.bar` and `foobar` in `foobar`). It's not clear what OP's desired behavior is in the latter case.

Comment: @Jordan: Updated the answer to reflect your thoughts, thanks.